# IOUtil Error Loading Stanford Shift Reduce Parser

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am attempting to upgrade my version of Stanford CoreNLP to the latest edition (was previously on v3.5.2, tried to upgrade to v3.6.0). After compiling all of the new jars necessary for v3.6.0, I started up a standalone Stanford CoreNLP server (using Apache Thrift v0.9.3).

In addition, I am using Stanford's Shift Reduce Parser, which can be found at the following link: [Stanford Shift Reduce Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml). I believe the latest version of the model was published on 10/23/2014. The model I need in particular is the englishSR.beam.ser.gz (English Beam Search Shift Reduce Model).

Unfortunately, upon running my new server (Stanford CoreNLP v3.6.0 / Apache Thrift v0.9.3), the logs displayed an error:

```
Reading in configuration from scripts/config...
Initializing Parser...
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.6 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.5 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.5 sec].
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
May 20, 2016 3:41:00 AM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 83 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
May 20, 2016 3:41:01 AM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 267 rules
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
May 20, 2016 3:41:01 AM edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor appendRules
INFO: Read 25 rules
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.4 sec].
03:41:01.566 [main] ERROR edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.beam.ser.gz ... 
done [10.4 sec].
Initializing Tokenizer...
The CoreNLP server is running...
```

Conversely, this is the log that is seen when running the old server (Stanford CoreNLP v3.5.2 / Thrift v0.9.3):

```
Reading in configuration from scripts/config...
Initializing Parser...
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.3 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.1 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [2.7 sec].
Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath: edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt
Reading TokensRegex rules from edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.5 sec].
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.beam.ser.gz ... done [9.8 sec].
Adding annotator dcoref
Initializing Tokenizer...
The CoreNLP server is running...
```

As you can see, the new server errors out while trying to load in the srparser and does not end up "Adding annotator dcoref". I did not modify any of the other files and am unsure what could have caused the discrepancy. Currently looking for a Stanford Core NLP properties file, but I would appreciate any help regarding this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you have the English models jar in your CLASSPATH.  You can download that jar here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html ... that jar definitely contains the shift reduce parser file

Comment: Also you might be interested in this: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Also, I am unsure why you say "rebuilt with ant"...if you want to use v3.6.0 all you need is the jar stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar and the appropriate dependencies and models...everything you need is available here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - apologies for being a bit vague in my description. The corenlp-server implementation was not available at the time that I started my project, and so I have a separate implementation that uses 'ant' to build a wrapper jar that encapsulates all of the jars that I need for my unique setup. I am definitely planning on looking to see if I can swap over to the corenlp-server that you linked in the near future though (much less overhead). I am fairly certain that the English models jar is there; but let me double check and report back.

Comment: So upon checking up on my jars, it does seem that I have the required necessary English models jar. It seemed to me that there was an issue with the shift reduce parser English model (which is a separate entity located at the link I provided above: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml). This model is provided separately because it is larger on the filesize side, and the one that I want is the beam search shift reduce parser English model. To my knowledge, this model has not changed between version 3.5.2 and 3.6.0, so my main concern was that I was missing some other new dependency.

Comment: Also make sure you are just using the English models jar and don't include whatever you downloaded from the shift reduce link.  The shift reduce model is distributed in the English models jar now.  We have made a huge English models jar which contains EVERYTHING.

Comment: It's possible the model supplied with that older shift reduce jar is broken with 3.6.0, so I'll investigate and update that page.  Moving forward we just want people to download the full English jar if they want extra resources like the shift reduce model, but there may be some pages I haven't updated yet!

Comment: It seems to work fine with this jar as well, so I am not sure what is going on: stanford-srparser-2014-10-23-models.jar

Comment: Yeah, I just took everything out except for the stuff from the new CoreNLP 3.6.0 packages and it still gives me the same problem. I tried to replace jars one at a time to see what would throw me the IOUtil error, and upgrading all the jar dependencies (joda-time, jollyday, etc) did not pose any problems. Even the new English model (the huge one) doesn't break when used with the 3.5.2 version of CoreNLP. Issue arises when I swap out stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar and stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar to their respective 3.6.0 counterparts...

Comment: I would also like to note that it seems like the CoreNLP server that has the error thrown still parses fine on the most part, although it is missing the "dcoref" annotations (which makes sense because that does not show up in the logs). Not sure what else I could be missing, but still checking around. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: When I download the distribution folder stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09.zip and the English jar file stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar from here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html and run the command in my answer it works fine.  I would first see if you can replicate my command.  I changed it to explicitly refer to what I downloaded from the main download page.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response/absence from this conversation -- I have been away. I replicated your commands with no problem, and even added the dcoref annotator without issue it seems. One thing that I did notice was that I was using log4j12 in conjunction with slf4j for logging purposes, but I didn't think that would cause any issues. I also made sure I was running Java 8 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (8u91), but the exact same error still occurs. Will continue looking to see what else I could be potentially missing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command and had no issues:

```
java -Xmx6g -cp "stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*:stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse -file sample-text.txt -outputFormat text -parse.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.beam.ser.gz
```

This is using the distribution for Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 and the latest model jars we use.

Make sure to just use those jars and only those jars, if you have older versions of things floating around in your CLASSPATH that could cause compatibility issues which might makes things not work.

And just to be clear the distribution comes with a standard models jar which has some basic things to use the toolkit.  Then separately there is the English models jar which is HUGE and contains ALL English resources.

The English shift reduce parser models are all in the English models jar we distribute now which has ALL English resources.  That is the recommended way to get English resources not available in the standard jar.  I may need to update some pages to reflect this information.  It's possible the old shift reduce models jar is not compatible with 3.6.0, I will investigate.

All of these things are available here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

If you are still having issues let me know, and let me know where the jar causing the problem is coming from and I will investigate.  But if you run that command with the resources downloaded from the link above it should work fine.

Comment: Posted a reply at the bottom of my question and unsure if you were able to see it; perhaps we could move this to a chat? The standard distribution seems to work fine standalone but my makeshift server/client implementation may be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Did you call ShiftReduceParser.loadModel method?

This method calls IOUtils.readObjectAnnouncingTimingFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem method, and its source is as follows:

```
try {
  Timing timing = new Timing();
  logger.error(msg + ' ' + path + " ... ");
  obj = IOUtils.readObjectFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(path);
  timing.done();
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
  throw new RuntimeIOException(e);
}
return obj;
```

"logger.error" is a mistake probably. It shoud be "logger.info", I think.

Comment: I did call the loadModel() method, but a bit unsure as to what your claim is. Do you mean to say that the error message is misleading?

Everything seems to parse fine even with the error in loading the model file listed above, minus the coref annotations made by the 'dcoref annotator', which doesn't seem to be loaded in.